# how to add only attribute on tag inside map javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to add only attribute on tag inside map

```
{Object.keys(data.countryStatus).map(function (key, i) {
    <input type="checkbox" {true ? "defaultchecked" : ""} />
 });
}
```

Comment: do you mean readOnly?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your problem correctly then to set defaultChecked you need to do this as follows:

```
{Object.keys(data.countryStatus).map(function (key, i) {
    <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={true} />
 });
}
```